# tensorflow trained detection model works only on fixed position

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

I retrained an object detection model `ssd_inception_v2_cooco` to detect a custom object, and it works great on test cases **the same size** as the training set.

But when i either resize the test picture or move the object i want to detect around in the picture (to other place than it appeared in the training set) - the detection fails.

In my training set i used pictures with the target object more or less in the same position in every picture (upper right part).

I thought that maybe i should add more items to the training set with random positions of the target object, but then i flipped the picture horizontally (the target object was on the upper left instead of upper right and also was **mirrored**) using mspaint and the detection succeeded.

Thats where i get confused and i'd love if anyone can tell me what i am doing wrong or giving me some tips to overcome it.

Thanks alot!

**EDIT:**

just to make it easier to understand, this is an illustration, not the actual target object/background etc..

This example gets 99% score, you can think of it as a picture from the training set:

[99.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddXNE.png)

the same image, mirrored also gets 99% score:

[99_mirrored.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMMAk.png)

this is where the object **lowered down** a little bit using mspaint, **gets around 94%**:

[94.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssagJ.png)

this is the same image as the first (99%) image just cropped from the bottom > up. here the object is **NOT** detected at all:

[0.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZykuI.png)

**EDIT 2:**

As Mark stated in the comments, more details:

Code and environment: I followed this tutorial here, https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html didn't change anything in the code.

About the training sets, the vast majority of the images are 720x480, and most of the times the target object is placed at the top right of each image.

Comment: I think that more details about your training (hyper-parameters, regularization methods, etc.) and dataset (sizes and examples) would help. Regarding the mirrored image behavior, maybe part of your training uses horizontal flipping? Code would also help

Comment: Hi Mark, about the code and everything, i followed this tutorial here, https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html, didn't change anything in the code.
About the training sets, the vast majority of the images are 720x480, and most of the times the target object is placed at the top right of each image.